# Calculating a Rolling Average with Missing Time Values

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, calculated-columns, zoo

I have a dataset described by the following:

```
> dput(droplevels(head(sample,10)))
structure(list(Team = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Air-Force", class = "factor"), Year = c(2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L
), Grouped_Position_3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Skill", class = "factor"), Avg_Rating = c(0.7667, 
0, 0.7444, 0.7222, 0, 0.7556, 0.76224, 0.596322222222222, 0.706584615384615, 
0.767509090909091), n = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 13L, 
11L)), .Names = c("Team", "Year", "Grouped_Position_3", "Avg_Rating", 
"n"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

In the full dataset there are multiple schools, grouped positions and years. What I'm trying to do is figure out how to generate a rolling average using the current year and four years in the past for each unique group of school, year and position. For example for 2013, Air Force and Skill position I would like the following calculation to take place (Note that 2010 is missing in the data):

(.767+.70+.59+0+.762)/5

The 0 comes from the missing year. I have looked at the zoo library in combination with dplyr but I haven't been able to control for missing values like this. Am I looking at having to write a loop or is there some package in r that has this capability?

Answer (score 3):

Create a function `Avg` which given a vector of row numbers `ix` takes the required average of the most recent 5 years and then `rollapplyr` it for each group of `Team` and `Grouped_Position_3`:

```
library(zoo)

Avg <- function(ix) with(sample[ix, ], sum(Avg_Rating[Year >= max(Year) - 4]) / 5)
transform(sample, Avg = ave(1:nrow(sample), Team, Grouped_Position_3, FUN = 
   function(ix) rollapplyr(ix, 5, Avg, partial = TRUE)))
```

giving:

```
        Team Year Grouped_Position_3 Avg_Rating  n       Avg
1  Air-Force 2003              Skill  0.7667000  1 0.1533400
2  Air-Force 2004              Skill  0.0000000  1 0.1533400
3  Air-Force 2005              Skill  0.7444000  3 0.3022200
4  Air-Force 2006              Skill  0.7222000  6 0.4466600
5  Air-Force 2007              Skill  0.0000000  1 0.4466600
6  Air-Force 2008              Skill  0.7556000  1 0.4444400
7  Air-Force 2009              Skill  0.7622400  5 0.5968880
8  Air-Force 2011              Skill  0.5963222  9 0.4228324
9  Air-Force 2012              Skill  0.7065846 13 0.5641494
10 Air-Force 2013              Skill  0.7675091 11 0.5665312
```

### Note

The input used is:

```
sample <- structure(list(Team = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Air-Force", class = "factor"), Year = c(2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L
), Grouped_Position_3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Skill", class = "factor"), Avg_Rating = c(0.7667, 
0, 0.7444, 0.7222, 0, 0.7556, 0.76224, 0.596322222222222, 0.706584615384615, 
0.767509090909091), n = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 13L, 
11L)), .Names = c("Team", "Year", "Grouped_Position_3", "Avg_Rating", 
"n"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: So when I try to run this function (as in just run the code to make it a callable function)I get an error. I notice that it does show up as a usable function in my R studio pane though, is this an issue? Error below.
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame

Comment: If you copy and paste the code in the Note and then in the body of the answer it does not give an error message.  You must have done something else but we can't know what you have done unless you provide a reproducible example.